# Blueprint API - How to add different ports for API calls, in the same serverurl?

Tags: api, blueprint, apiblueprint

I would like to add a different port for each call, but the same server URL, and I can't manage that.

for example:
{{ServerURL}}:59310/account
{{ServerURL}}:59313/inventory

how can I add the port?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you, I had made a few changes, I hopt that it is more clear now